# Schengen Visa Query

Tags: schengen, croatia

I will be visiting Croatia, Slovenia, and Austria in October, Croatia being the first point of entry.

- Croatia: 8 nights
- Slovenia: 5 nights
- Austria: 4 nights

I am leaving India on 14th October and getting back on 31st October. However, there is a transit flight in Frankfurt, Germany, before entering Croatia.

I am filling out the visa application form and I am not sure about the following fields:

- Member States of destination: what should I mention here? Croatia?
- Member State of first entry: Should this be Croatia, germany, or Slovenia?

Please help me as I am really confused.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you need either a Croatian visa, or a **multiple entry Schengen visa** to enter Croatia, since they're not a part of the Schengen Area. See this: http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/

Croatia can't be a point of entry to the **Schengen** territory.

If you are going to Croatia directly from India, without leaving the airport in Germany, you shouldn't normally clear immigration in Frankfurt. Meaning, your first entry will be in **Slovenia**.

However, if you will be *staying* - not just changing planes at the airport - in Frankfurt, you'll clear immigration, and your first entry will be in **Germany**. If so, if you will have to re-check your baggage in Frankfurt (that depends on your itinerary).